# MySqlParameter with float value of 0.0

Tags: mysql, .net, mysql.data, mysql-parameter

I constructed a MySqlParameter with `MySqlParameter tmp1 = new MySqlParameter("?tmp1", 0.0);` and when executing the corresponding `insert` query received the error message that the respective column cannot be null.

When investigating that parameter in Visual Studio's debugger, its `Value` property is shown as `null`, though I think that `0.0` and `null`are different things.

Anyway, when I set the value later on with `tmp1.Value = 0.0;`, the parameter's value is correctly shown as `0`. (Note: different values like `1` work  correctly in the constructor).

Is that a feature of the constructor of `MySqlParameter` (MySql.Data.6.9.8, net45) or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85027

but comments on that page indicate that some people think of it as a feature...